# Изменение размера полей таблицы в HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

Добрый день.

Имеются две таблицы (тег table). Одна расположена точно под другой. В верхней таблице одна строка. В нижней "икс" строк. Количество столбцов в верхней и нижней таблицах точно совпадает.

Вопрос: как назначить каждому из столбцов верхней таблицы ширину, равную ширине соответствующего столбца нижней таблицы? Загвоздка в том, что я использую Ангуляр. Т.е., конечно, можно пройти по DOM и там попробовать поменять. Но на момент, когда запускается соответствующий кусок кода в скрипте, представление (view) Ангуляра ещё не отобразило данные из модели, и код просто видит пустую таблицу.

Comment: почему не использовать одну таблицу?

Comment: возможно потому что нижняя таблица будет скролиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй ng-init, он запускается после загрузки страницы.

Следующий пример только для одной первой колонки, но принцип понятен.

```
<div ng-controller="syncCollController" ng-init="init()">
<style>
    td {
        background: lightblue;
    }
</style>
{{name}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-style="col1Style">head 1</td>
        <td>head 2</td>
        <td>head 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="col1">Row 1 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
app.controller('syncCollController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.col1Style = { width: "0px" };

    $scope.init = function () {
        var col1 = angular.element(document.querySelector("#col1"));
        $scope.col1Style = { width: col1.prop("clientWidth") + "px" };
    };
}]);
</script>
```